# Make a menu item visible for logged out users on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, menuitem, wp-nav-menu-item

I'm facing a problem kinda weird.

I've edited and set the wp-login.php page to my brand and set the redirections such as: 

 costumer > my account (after login)

 admin/editor > admin panel (after login)

 and so on.

 But my problem lies in the menu I'm using. Even after I've set the redirections I tried adding the wp-login.php page as a custom iten on my menu, but it only appeared to logged in users and I haven't set it to to do so. 

 I would like to make it visible for both *logged in and logged out users* but as much as I try it doesn't seem to work.

PS: I'm using the free version of OcenWP and their default menu for my website

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple (free) plugins for wordpress for this purpose. One example is:
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/user-menus/